# How to make piechart hiegher in recharts

Tags: reactjs, pie-chart, recharts

How to make pie chart higher in recharts? There is empty space in container and I would like to spread chart, how?

My code is:

```
        <ResponsiveContainer
            height={285} 
        >
            <PieChart
                margin={{ top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 }}  
            >
                <Pie 
                    data={datasets} 
                    innerRadius={60}
                    outerRadius={80}
                    fill="#8884d8"
                    paddingAngle={0}
                    dataKey="value" 
                >
                    {
                        datasets.map((_, index: number) => <Cell key={backgroundColor[index]} fill={backgroundColor[index]} />)
                    }
                </Pie> 
            </PieChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/op0cq2ja/4/

See problem on image:
[image]

Comment: can you share your code with any sandBox or codePen?

Comment: @Yoel sure I can https://jsfiddle.net/op0cq2ja/4/

Comment: @testomalta https://jsfiddle.net/p3q60e27/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the radius of your pie chart, change `Pie`'s `outerRadius` prop.

You can also change the `innerRadius` prop to increase or decrease the area of the hole in the center of the pie.